# What is the bug in this in c qsort function

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to run same calculate function with c++ and it works as expected but not with c, could you please tell what is wrong. I am just sorting two arrays comparing value and incrementing answer;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_function(const void *a,const void *b) {
    int *x = (int *) a;
    int *y = (int *) b;
    return *x - *y;
}

int calculate(long long A[], long long G[],int t){
    int answer = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < t) {
        if(G[i] > A[j]){
            i++;
            j++;
            answer++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    int p; 
    scanf("%d", &p);

    while (p > 0){
        int t; 
        scanf("%d", &t);
        long long  G[t];
        long long  A[t];

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
            scanf("%d",&G[i]);
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
            scanf("%d",&A[i]);

        qsort(G,t,sizeof (long long ),compare_function);
        qsort(A,t,sizeof (long long ),compare_function);

        printf("%d\n", calculate(A,G,t));

        p--;
    }
}
```

I have used c(gcc 8.2.0) and one weird thing is every time I ran this program I got differ output.

```
    Array Input

    1
    10
    3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1 
    2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6 

    output: 6, expected : 7

    constraints
        1<= N <=100000
        0<= Array elemts <= LLONG_MAX
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&A);` looks suspicious. Did you mean `scanf("%d",&A[t]);`? Also note that `%lld` is needed for `long long`. `gcc` should have warned you.

Comment: One thing to try: print each array before sorting; if the data looks fine upon input but is broken after the sort, or it's bad right after input, will help you narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: What does the `calculate` function calculate? Moreover, I can't reproduce your error even after multiple tries.

Comment: @asds_asds Calculate function compare values of the array, sort two array, compare the value of the first array with the second array if the value is greater it will increment the count and move the pointer forward pointer else just move pointer forward of first array

Comment: @numzero Yes you were right %lld worked